# How to fix custom alerts function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been experimenting with custom alerts, and this is what I've come up with so far:

```js
window.CustomAlert = function(parameters) {
    var alert = document.createElement("div");
    var title = parameters.title !== undefined ? parameters.title : "ALERT!";
    var message = parameters.message !== undefined ? parameters.message : "Hello World!";
    var type = parameters.type !== undefined ? parameters.type : "";
    var color = type === "info" ? "#2196F3" : type === "success" ? 
        "#4CAF50" : type === "warning" ? "#ff9800" : type === "danger" ? "#f44336" : "#000000";
    document.body.appendChild(alert);
    alert.style.margin = "auto";
    alert.style.position = "absolute";
    alert.style.top = "0";
    alert.style.left = "0";
    alert.style.border = "1px solid black";
    alert.style.maxHeight = "350px";
    alert.style.width = "99.8%";
    alert.style.minHeight = "70px";
    alert.style.color = "white";
    alert.style.background = "#fff";
    alert.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
    alert.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    alert.style.overflow = "auto";
    alert.innerHTML = `
        <span style="float:right;font-size:25px;cursor:pointer;color:black;padding:7px;background:red" 
            onclick="this.parentElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentElement)"
        >&times;</span>

        //title
        <div style="background:` + color + `;padding:15px;height:30%">
            <p>` + title + `</p>
        </div>
        //message
        <div style="background:#ccc;padding:15px;height:80%">
            <p>` + message + `</p>
        </div>
    `;
};

CustomAlert({
    title: "LOG:",
    message: "Document initialized.",
    type: "info"
});
```

...then there will be 3 problems:
1) There'll be an annoying gap between the title and message boxes;
2) The span function only closes the title box; and
3) The heights of the title and message don't work.
How do I fix these?

Comment: may I know the objective of doing custom code, I thing there are many dialog javascript framework available like JQuery UI etc..,

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire Learning maybe?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the white gap actually contains your text "//title" and "//message". Removing these comments (which are actually in your html code), removed the white gaps for me. Otherwise you can use `<!-- title -->` and `<!-- message -->` in your html code to comment your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem new to JS, I will first give you some pointers how to generally improve the code:

- Use CSS for alert style, do not use inline styles. It adds too many lines to your code
- Define alert types as enum-like object:

  ```
  const CustomAlertType = {
      info: {color:"#2196F3"},
      success: {color:"#4CAF50"},
      warning: {color:"#ff9800"},
      danger: {color:"#f44336"},
      defaultValues: {color:  "#000000"}
  }
  ```
- Since you're using string template, you can do this: `value=${variable}`
- Do not append `alert` before you set it's `innerHTML`. It has an impact on the browser, because it needs to validate the DOM tree. For that matter, try to not use `innerHTML` unless you need to
- Do not use callbacks in HTML like this: `<elm onclick=...` Instead, you can do this: `alert.querySelector("span.close").addEventListener("click",`. After that, the HTML shrinks a lot and is easier to read:

  ```
  alert.innerHTML = `
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div class="title" style="background:${typeObj.color};">
          <p>${title}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
          <p>${message}</p>
      </div>
  `;
  ```
- You should probably have a callback when the alert is closed, eg. `parameters.onclose`
- As a special treat, I added an example how to use alert callback in async function, so that it acts almost like `window.alert`

The final code after those fixes:

```
/**
 * @enum
 * Defines properties for different alert types
 *
**/
const CustomAlertType = {
    info: {color:"#2196F3"},
    success: {color:"#4CAF50"},
    warning: {color:"#ff9800"},
    danger: {color:"#f44336"},
    defaultValues: {color:  "#000000"}
}

window.CustomAlert = function(parameters) {
    var alert = document.createElement("div");
    alert.classList.add("customAlert");
    var title = parameters.title !== undefined ? parameters.title : "ALERT!";
    var message = parameters.message !== undefined ? parameters.message : "Hello World!";
    // Type must be string, of not string use default
    var type = typeof parameters.type == "string" ? parameters.type : "defaultValues";
    // If the type is not valid, it will fall back to default
    const typeObj = CustomAlertType[type] || CustomAlertTyle.defaultValues;


    alert.innerHTML = `
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="title" style="background:${typeObj.color};">
            <p>${title}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <p>${message}</p>
        </div>
    `;
    // After close is clicked, alert is destroyed and callback is called
    alert.querySelector("span.close").addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert.parentNode.removeChild(alert);
        // If there is a close callback, call it so that code can continue
        if(typeof parameters.onclose == "function") {
            parameters.onclose();
        }
    });
    document.body.appendChild(alert);
};
// Allows to await on alert being closed in `async` functions
function CustomAlertAsync(parameters) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        parameters.onclose = resolve;
        CustomAlert(parameters);
    });
}
// Example of for loop that waits on alerts to be confirmed
(async ()=>{
    for(let i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        await CustomAlertAsync({title:"for() loop", type: "info", message: "Message #"+(i+1)});
    }
})();
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 800px;
}

.customAlert {
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 350px;
  width: 99.8%;
  color: white;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: auto;
}
.customAlert .close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  padding: 7px;
  background: red;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
.customAlert .title {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 2em;
}
.customAlert .message {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/o5rbLya9/27/

I am not quite sure what did you mean by this though:

> 3) The heights of the title and message don't work

I really think you should make a separate question on [html](/questions/tagged/html)+[css](/questions/tagged/css) that will just use HTML example with CSS and without the javascript part. You can get the HTML of the alert using dev tools.

Comment: can you convert the CSS into JS?

Comment: Why would you want that? Separating CSS and JS is a major point of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Change JS comment `//` to html comment tag `<!-- -->`. `innerHTML` gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element.
2. onclick removes the alert box now, what element you want removes? 3
3. Add height with 100% to alert

See code below

```js
window.CustomAlert = function(parameters) {
    var alert = document.createElement("div");
    var content = document.createElement("div"); // body content example
    content.innerHTML = "Body content"; // body content example
    var title = parameters.title !== undefined ? parameters.title : "ALERT!";
    var message = parameters.message !== undefined ? parameters.message : "Hello World!";
    var type = parameters.type !== undefined ? parameters.type : "";
    var color = type === "info" ? "#2196F3" : type === "success" ? 
        "#4CAF50" : type === "warning" ? "#ff9800" : type === "danger" ? "#f44336" : "#000000";
    document.body.appendChild(alert);
    document.body.appendChild(content);
    alert.style.margin = "auto";
    alert.style.position = "absolute";
    alert.style.top = "0";
    alert.style.left = "0";
    alert.style.border = "1px solid black";
    alert.style.maxHeight = "350px";
    alert.style.width = "99.8%";
    alert.style.minHeight = "70px";
    alert.style.height = "100%"; // fixes for inner elements height
    alert.style.color = "white";
    alert.style.background = "#fff";
    alert.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
    alert.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    alert.style.overflow = "auto";
    alert.innerHTML = `
        <span style="float:right;font-size:25px;cursor:pointer;color:black;padding:7px;background:red" 
            onclick="this.parentElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentElement)"
        >&times;</span>

        <!-- title -->
        <div style="background:` + color + `;padding:15px;height:30%">
            <p>` + title + `</p>
        </div>
        <!-- message -->
        <div style="background:#ccc;padding:15px;height:80%">
            <p>` + message + `</p>
        </div>
    `;
};

CustomAlert({
    title: "LOG:",
    message: "Document initialized.",
    type: "info"
});
```